# SQL - Select the last register in a join

Tags: php, sql, join

I need to take the last (fechaDesde field) register in a join, i want only the last record and i have this table:

[relObrSocPaciente]

```
idPaciente  |   idObraSocial|   fechaDesde
    1       |       1       |   2018-07-29 21:49:46
    1       |       2       |   2017-07-29 21:49:46
    1       |       3       |   2019-07-30 00:00:00
    2       |       3       |   2018-07-30 21:49:46
    1       |       4       |   2001-07-29 21:49:46
    1       |       5       |   2018-07-30 23:49:46
```

I have this query:

```
SELECT p.idPaciente, p.nombre, p.apellido, p.email, o.descOSoc
    FROM pacientes p 
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT r.idPaciente, r.idObraSocial, max(r.fechaDesde) MaxDate
            FROM relObrSocPaciente r
            group by r.idPaciente ) rel on p.idPaciente = rel.idPaciente
    INNER JOIN obrasocial o ON rel.idObraSocial = o.idOSocial
    WHERE p.estado = '0'
    ORDER by rel.MaxDate DESC
```

And the issue is in the inner select:

```
SELECT r.idPaciente, r.idObraSocial, max(r.fechaDesde) MaxDate
            FROM relObrSocPaciente r
            group by r.idPaciente
```

will bring:

```
idPaciente  |   idObraSocial|   fechaDesde
    1       |       1       |   2019-07-30 00:00:00
    2       |       3       |   2018-07-30 21:49:46
```

and the fisrt record is not on my DB; it should be:

```
    1       |       3       |   2019-07-30 00:00:00
```

I'm running out of imagination, please help.
THANKS!

Comment: What does "take the last register in a join" mean? The rest of your post is not clear either. Explain what "the issue is" & what "it should be". What outputs go with what queries & what inputs & which are wrong cases & what is the desired case? See [mcve].

Comment: You say you have one table, but your query references multiple tables.

Comment: is not relevant other table info; but:
[PAciente] = {idPaciente + nombre + apellido +email} 
[ObraSocial] = {idObraSocial+ descripcion}

Comment: What does this request have to do with PHP? And what DBMS are you asking this for? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? PostgreSQL? ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

```
SELECT tf.idPaciente, tf.nombre, tf.apellido, tf.email, o.descOSoc, r.fechadesde
FROM pacientes tf 
LEFT JOIN relObrSocPaciente r on tf.idPaciente = r.idPaciente
LEFT JOIN obrasocial o on r.idObraSocial = o.idOSocial
WHERE r.fechaDesde in ( SELECT max( fechadesde )
                       FROM relObrSocPaciente
                       WHERE idPaciente = tf.idPaciente )
```